# calculation after converting nvarchar to datetime/date

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I am trying to mimic this calculation from Excel into T-SQL.

The first value is "7/25/2021  6:44:00 AM"

The second value is "7/25/2021  1:10:00 PM"

I am trying to come up with the **value of 0.35138..**

[image]

In SQL table, both values are currently in nvarchar(max) data type.

I am trying to write SQL Function, and I am stuck with process of Convert or Cast and do the calculation of two values.

So far, this is what I have:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[fn_break_cal] (
    @Punch_Start nvarchar(max),
    @Punch_End nvarchar(max)
 ) 

  RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS

BEGIN   
DECLARE @return_value nvarchar(max);

    SET @return_value = 
    
        CONVERT(varchar, @Punch_Start, 103)

RETURN @return_value
```

First, I am not sure how to do subtraction after I convert into date or datetime.

Whenver I use Datediff, output is Integer, and I am not sure how to make it to numeric like (0.35133..).

What is best approach of dealing with data from nvarchar(max) --> calculation of date/datetime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the DDL and Data to try?

Comment: Can you add the calculation please ?

Comment: @Gudwlk Thanks for your help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the below added function and the function call.  I am not sure why you return nvarchar(max) value in the function. I changed that to Decimal. I used CAST to cast the nvarchar to datetime. you can use TRY_CAST as well.

```
  ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[fn_break_cal] (
    @Punch_Start nvarchar(max),
    @Punch_End nvarchar(max)
    ) 

    RETURNS decimal(36, 8) AS

    BEGIN   
        DECLARE @return_value nvarchar(max);

         SET @return_value = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(@Punch_Start AS datetime2) ,  CAST(@Punch_End AS datetime2) ) / (24* 60.0)     

        RETURN @return_value
     END
```

Function call with params and return value:

```
       Select [dbo].[fn_break_cal] ('7/25/2021 6:44:00 AM','7/25/2021 15:10:00 PM') return_value
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
    DECLARE @ps nvarchar(30) = '7/25/2021 6:44:00 AM'
    DECLARE @pe nvarchar(30) = '7/25/2021 15:10:00 PM'
    
    SELECT
      DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @ps), TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @pe)) / (24 * 60.0) AS fraction
    
    SELECT
      LEFT(CONVERT(time, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @pe) - TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @ps)), 5) AS ' hr : mm '

-- more than 24 hrs
DECLARE @ps nvarchar(30) = '7/25/2021 6:44:00 AM'
DECLARE @pe nvarchar(30) = '7/27/2021 15:10:00 PM'

SELECT
  CONCAT((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @ps), TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @pe)) / 60),
  ':',
  (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @ps), TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @pe)) % 60)) ' hr : mm '
```